# roots blower pressure on Detroit 2 cycle Diesel 371 cubic inches

Tags: air-intake, tractor, forced-induction

I need the blower pressure for a Detroit 2 cycle Diesel 371 cubic inch Oliver 99 tractor

Comment: Just a note, the "371 cubic inch" is not the actual displacement. The -71 Series Detroit actually displaces 71 cubic inches per cylinder. All of the various models maintain the same piston, rings, connecting rod, and bearings, between the different models. The engine designated as a "3-71" is a three cylinder engine and displaces a total of 213 cubic inches. I worked on DD 3-71 engines in the Army which were installed in Gamma-Goat vehicles. I also worked on 6-71 and 8V-71 engines as well. Working on the Fuel injection rack for the 8-71 was a bugger, to say the least.

Comment: The internet reckons this guy can help you:  Peter@TractorData.com

Answer (score 1):

While I don't know the exact pressure of the 3-71 blower on the [Detroit Diesel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detroit_Diesel_Series_71) engines, it's actually quite minimal. It is meant as an air mover, which does pressurize the system, but nothing that great. From an educated guess standpoint, probably in the 1-2 psi range. The Detroit Series 71, being a 2-cycle diesel engine, uses the blower to ensure proper intake flow through the engine and into the cylinder. Each blower is matched to the size of the engine to give it the proper amount of air flow to serve this purpose. When you put this same blower onto an engine of smaller displacement and/or increase the speed of the blower in relation to the engine speed, you will get more pressure out of it. This is dependent upon many factors and would only be a guess as to what the outcome would be.